# POST /ott/v1/send - Send Triggered Messages Via the Chat Messaging API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to follow the below instuction to send the FACEBOOK MESSENGER messages using CHAT API.  I am NOT getting the syntax of JSON request.

> **Send Triggered Messages Via the Chat Messaging API** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm?search_text=ott

*Note: I was able to register my Facebook page SUCCESSFULLY* as per "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#!"

[image]

I did some R & D but, did NOT found any resource on the end point **POST /ott/v1/send**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's within that document you linked if you click on "more details" under JSON parameters.

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/OTTsendMessageToRecipient.htm)

It provides an example of what the message would like for different situations and the different types of error responses you might receive. I copied below from the reference:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /ott/v1/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "messageKey": "e1c35141-6e5c-4bc2-813b-60f969e52b0d",
    "messageGroupKey": "CanBeAGUIDorAny100UnicodeCharString",
    "from": {
        "senderType": "messenger",
        "senderId": "503868699681937"
    },
    "to": {
        "ottId": "FBfacdb735074f7c492c0bf190fa99020",
        "userReference": "1938cd4d34cc4db0b109756b8a9b14ff"
    },
    "message": {
        "subject": "Message Name",
        "contents": [{
                "type": "text",
                "text": "thanks for purchase"
        }],
        "customKeys": [{
            "messagingType": "RESPONSE"
        }]
    },
    "validityPeriod": 30
}
```